# Usage of parameters for IIFE and namespace

Tags: javascript

I am going through some code which is making use of google maps API .

```
function initMap(){
(function(google , window){
var center = {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), center);    
})(google , window);
}
```

So I understand IIFE and how it prevents global scope pollution but I do not understand what passing the global objects google and window to the IIFE ,  achieve in the above code . 
Could someone please explain what is the advantage of using this pattern and what exactly are we doing with the google and window object inside the IIFE?

Comment: Actually it is quite senseless.

Answer (score 1):

> what exactly are we doing with the google and window object inside the IIFE?

Nothing useful, and nothing respectively.

`window` isn't used at all inside the function.

`google` is used, but synchronously. If it was used asynchronously then it might be useful to pass it so its value didn't get [overwritten between multiple uses of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), but that isn't the case here.